# DC.js, Crossfilter - fake group vs. data merge for cross tabular data

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have three CSV files feeding into one DC dashboard. The first has 100 rows (one per company) and 30 fields, and is organised in a crossfilter-friendly way. The second file also has 100 rows (one per company), but has 40 related "factor" names arranged cross-tabular. The third file has one row per company / month combination, e.g. Company A-March 2017, Company A-Feb 2017 etc.

E.g. File 1

```
Company 1---Dimension1---Dimension2---etc
Company 2---Dimension1---Dimension2---etc
etc. for 100 rows
```

File 2

```
Company1---Factor1---Factor2---Factor3---Factor4---etc for 40
Company2---Factor1---Factor2---Factor3---Factor4---etc for 40
etc. for 100 rows
```

**N.B. A single visualisation needs to cover all 40 factors, i.e. 40 factors = 1 dimension.**

File 3

```
Company1---Month1---Dimension4---Dimension5---Dimension6
Company1---Month2---Dimension4---Dimension5---Dimension6
Company1---Month3---Dimension4---Dimension5---Dimension6
etc for 100 companies x 12 months
```

My aim is to create one boxplot for each of 40 factors, merging the data in the most efficient way because 100 rows is only a small sample. The decision is: merge data vs. use fake groups. This decision will be repeated on the time chart too. If I merge data my 100 rows will become 60k rows.

I've got it working using a fake group. I couldn't get reduce() to work on groupAll() and so I'm gathering the data for each company, processing it afterwards and creating a fake group. Is there a better method for a file of 1000, or 5000 companies?

Thanks

Emma

```
  var idDimBox = facts.dimension(function(d){ return d['id']; });
  var factorGrpBox = idDimBox.group().reduce(
    function(p,v){//addition function
      for (var i=0; i<factorFields[0].length; i++) { p[factorFields[0][i]] = v[factorFields[0][i]]; }
      return p;
  },
  function(p,v){//removal function

    for (var i=0; i<factorFields[0].length; i++) { p[factorFields[0][i]]=-1; }

    return p;
  },//end reduce Function

    function(){

      var obj = {};
      for (var i=0; i<factorFields[0].length; i++) {
        obj[factorFields[0][i]] = -1;
      }
      return obj;
    }

  );







var obj = factorGrpBox;//actually calls a separate function here

var tempFactor = obj.top(Infinity);//array of objects, 100 long
  for (var j=0; j<factorFields[0].length; j++) {
    factorFields[2][j] = [];
  }

  for (var i=0; i<tempFactor.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<factorFields[0].length; j++) {
      factorFields[2][j].push(tempFactor[i].value[factorFields[0][j]]);
    }
  }

  fakeBoxPlotGroup = {all: function() {
    var myarr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<factorFields[0].length; i++) {
      var myobj = {};
      myobj.key = factorFields[0][i];
      myobj.value = factorFields[2][i];
      myarr.push(myobj);

    }
    return myarr;
  }}
```

Comment: I probably haven't looked hard enough, but I don't see why you need to convert the factors into a columnar format assuming that they are each a separate measurement for a single company? I'm probably missing something. And combining the company-level data with the company/month data remains a problem. Any chance you can put together a small working example with sample data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The factors are already columnar / cross tabular in the CSV file, and all the factors need to go into a single visualisation, which will contain 40 boxplots. I can convert the data into crossfilter-friendly format (i.e. 2 columns, the first containing 1 of 40 factor names and the second containing the value). But this means massive repetition of the other data.

Comment: I'm thinking in this case you wouldn't want to do that conversion. Would require a dimension for each factor and using Crossfilter 1.4.0-alpha.06 which allows >32 dimensions. What does your data volume look like if you take that approach?

Comment: Sorry - what am I saying? It would require 40 *groups*. So any version of Crossfilter should probably work ok.